Exporting data from duckdb query composing filename with strftime
Trying to export a bunch of tables as csv from duckdb database I get an error on COPY when composing the filename with the timestamp this way:
COPY (SELECT * FROM main.mytable) TO CONCAT('C:\\Users\\rdata\\mytable_', strftime(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%M'), '.csv') (FORMAT 'csv', HEADER, DELIMITER '|')


Error Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "CONCAT"

Tried to compose this way too (to no avail):
COPY (SELECT * FROM main.mytable) TO 'C:\\Users\\rdata\\mytable_' || strftime(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%M') || '.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', HEADER, DELIMITER '|')


If you can't generate the string outside SQL (probably a better idea), you could try using hive partitioning and date formatting to generate something close:
COPY (
    SELECT *, now() as mytable 
    FROM main.mytable
) 
TO 'C:\\Users\\rdata\\') (
    FORMAT 'csv', 
    HEADER, 
    DELIMITER '|', 
    PARTITION_BY("mytable"),
    FILENAME_PATTERN 'mytable.csv'
    DATEFORMAT '%Y%m%d%H%M'
)

This should create a directory called mytable=<now> containing mytable.csv. Play around with it to see what works best for your use case.
